# How to cancel a print statement if a method is called with a certain parameter?

Tags: java, printing, non-static

I'm not sure if the question is very clear, maybe the code will help.

This is part of the constructor of SpaceGame

```
   player.setPlanets(planets); //set Planets for player

   enemy.setPlanets(planets); //set Planets for enemy
```

And this is part of the setPlanets method

```
public void setPlanets (ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) //Iterate through the ArrayList of Planets
        {
            System.out.println(planets.get(i)); //Prints the info of each planet
        }
```

When the game begins, planets are printed twice. Is there a way to cancel it if I use enemy.setPlanets?

Comment: All you do in `setPlanets()` is iterate through the list of planets and print them, so, just don't call `enemy.setPlanets`?

Comment: No this is only part of the code, I removed the rest for readability

Comment: `And this is the setPlanets method`  < That made me assume it is all of the setPlanets method. Please post all of it or specify that it is only *part* of the method

Comment: Separate your planet printing from your planet setting, then you can call: `printPlanets(planets); player.setPlanets(planets); enemy.setPlanets(planets);`

Comment: Thank you! So there is no way to modify setPlanets with an if statement or something like that?

Comment: Not sure if it has sense. If you set the same list for player and enemy, and try to print it, you must get each planet printed twice. If you want to get it just once, print it only in one of the setters

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean as a condition

```
public void setPlanets (ArrayList<Planet> planets, boolean print) {
    for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) //Iterate through the ArrayList of Planets
        {
           if (print) {
              System.out.println(planets.get(i)); //Prints the info of each planet
           }
        }


player.setPlanets(planets, true); //set Planets for player

enemy.setPlanets(planets, false); //set Planets for enemy
```

And more you can overload setPlanets

```
public void setPlanets (ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    setPlanets(planets, false); // don't print by default
}
```

Then for enemy,

```
enemy.setPlanets(planets);
```

is enough.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am told that I need to modify setPlanets so that it initializes all instances the Spaceship class at once (Player and Enemy) so I don't call it twice.

Comment: If you try to init player and enemy in one method, I suggest you create another method like inits() and call setPlanets twice. This way would make setPlanets reusable. If you just want to call setPlanets once, you have to use `if else` condition. But this would make setPlanets less reusable, which is not in keeping with object-oriented. It's more like procedure-oriented. Hope I make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I see there's two different info you will print. once for player and another for enemy so where is the problem it's different info, so if you want to print just one info when start the game you should write:

```
if (gameStarted){
     player.setPlanets(planets); //set Planets for player        
}else{
     player.setPlanets(planets); //set Planets for player        
     enemy.setPlanets(planets); //set Planets for enemy
}
```

or viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

I think bejond's answer is quite good, but it will check the print condition for each element of your loop.
You could check the condition before entering the loop to obtain better performances.

```
player.setPlanets(planets, true); //set Planets for player
enemy.setPlanets(planets, false); //set Planets for enemy
```

Your function should now look like that

```
public void setPlanets (ArrayList<Planet> planets, boolean isPrinted) 
{

        if (isPrinted) 
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) //Iterate through the ArrayList of Planets
           {
              System.out.println(planets.get(i)); //Prints the info of each planet
           }
        }

        //your code...
}
```

If you wish, you could also overload your function, like bejond suggested.

Comment: Sure thing, quite well. If there are more codes in loop, then if would have to be in code block.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am told that I need to modify setPlanets so that it initializes all instances the Spaceship class at once (Player and Enemy) so I don't call it twice.